# How can I get a list of ordered rows from a list of ordered ids from a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working in PHP, and I have a list of ids, which are ranked, with the first being the most important. I'm retrieving the rows using something like this (simplified for clarity):

```
$id_as_sql_list = implode("','", $id_list);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM books
WHERE id in ('$id_as_sql_list')";
```

This basically works out as:

```
WHERE id in ('456', '123', '789')
```

The problem is, the result from the database isn't coming back in the order of the list. What's the best way to get them back in this order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at order by field syntax.

This is an example

```
select * from table
where id in (x,y,z)
order by field(id,x,y,z)
```

Comment: Particularly useful to get data from MySQL for scores kept in Redis for instance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books
WHERE id in ('$id_as_sql_list')
ORDER BY YourRankingField ";
```

Answer (score 0):

use [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books
WHERE id in ('$id_as_sql_list') ORDER BY whatever";
```

where `whatever` is the field you wish to order by.

Comment: Obviously the question asked is to get the links from MySQL in the order of the ID's used in the query. 'order by whatever' is therefor not the answer to this question. Getting information in the order of the ID's given can be particularly useful when getting data from rows read from Redis (in a Redis/MySQL combi)